# Can you make an if statement for a function arguement?

Tags: python

Here's an example:

```py
def function(arg_1, arg_2="hi", arg_3="hello")
    if arg_2="hi":
```

Can you do that?

Comment: A function argument is just a variable.  Why wouldn't you be able to check it with an if statement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is

```py
def function(arg_1, arg_2="hi", arg_3="hello"):
    if arg_2 == "hi":
        # code
```

Comment: Don't forget the colon...

Comment: @Christophe My mistake! Didn't notice it when copying code over from the original answer